# PubSub is not a constructor apollo server

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am creating a subscription in apollo server. When I try to create a new instance of PubSub. I get
an error PubSub is not a constructor.

```
const {PubSub} = require("apollo-server")
const pubsub =  new PubSub()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by installing graphql-subscriptions, then requiring in PubSub from the later like this:

```
const {PubSub} = require("graphql-subscriptions")
```

Comment: when I did this, I got an error message: `server must support graphql-ws or subscriptions-transport-ws protocol.` Can you please explain how you got around that?

Comment: @Hugobop you resolved this issue ?